# C# dynamic class - how to preserved the var name from serialize output

Tags: c#, class, elasticsearch, serialization, dynamic

The variable name with @ prefix changed after serialize due C# naming. How to prevent this?

```
//assignment of object value with @Timestamp

List<dynamic> Documents = new List<dynamic>();
Documents.Add( new { Index = ""index-name-test", Type = "doc", Id = g.ToString(),
    Title = "title1", @Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow });

foreach (var doc in Documents)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Documents= doc });           
}
```

as in the json value, it contain

```
"{\"Documents\":{\"Index\":\"index-name-test*\",\"Type\":\"doc\",\"Id\":\"76134434-2ed0-48df-9034-841b386a0dbc\",\"Title\":\"title1\",\"Timestamp\":\"2019-04-14T15:50:33.596931Z\"}}"
```

> {"Documents":{"Index":"index-name-test*","Type":"doc","Id":"76134434-2ed0-48df-9034-841b386a0dbc","Title":"title1","Timestamp":"2019-04-14T15:50:33.596931Z"}}

How to make Timestamp become @Timestamp ?

Comment: The `@` symbol has a special meaning - it doesn't affect the variable name, but allows you to use any keyword as an identifier. Try using `JObject` or `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of anonymous object. Then you could name properties whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks mate, the Dictionary<string, object> solved my problem! however JObject  couldn't resolved my problem it produced the same result as i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, prefixing a variable name with `@` is just a way to allow you to use reserved words as variable names. For example, you can do this:

```
var @class = "foo";
```

If you don't use a `@` you will get a compiler error. As such, when you serialise your dynamic objects, the variable name is still `Timestamp`. The best option would be to use a concrete class to store your data. Not only can you then control the names when serialising, but you get compile time type safety and it's far quicker than using `dynamic` (every time you use `dynamic` a kitten dies!)

So I would create two classes like this:

```
//Root class so you don't need to serialise an anonymous type and can easily deserialise later
public class Root
{
    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    //This attribute controls the JSON property name
    [JsonProperty("@Timestamp")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

}
```

And serialise something like this:

```
var root = new Documents();

root.Documents = new List<Document>
{
    new Document
    {
        Index = ""index-name-test", 
        Type = "doc", 
        Id = g.ToString(),
        Title = "title1",
        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
    }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
```

Comment: Thank you David, the concrete class is what im having it now. and im looking any possibilities to make the design more flexible in real time execution, as in my use case, i might not able to pre-fixed all the class variables, as im collecting data from various log and ingest it into my storage, in this case ElasticSearch. Therefore i will having a config file define all variable and construct my object in realtime for data ingestion.